# Why my promisifed stub method doesn't resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, es6-promise, sinon

I have this authentication middleware:

```js
import { promisify } from 'util';

async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
    const [type, token] = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');

    try {
         const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.SECRET);
         
         req.userId = decoded.id;
         
         return next();
    } catch (error) {
         return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token.' });
    }
}
```

This is how I'm testing it:

```js
it('should return next and inject user id into the request', async () => { 
    req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer 1234577920fsdaf';

    sandbox.stub(jwt, 'verify').resolves({ id: 'bj435çsfkj' });

    await verifyToken(req, res, next);

    expect(req.userId).to.equal('bj435çsfkj');
    expect(next.calledOnce).to.be.true;
});
```

However, it seems to me that the promise isn't resolving. When I run the test, I get  `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves` on that test. Maybe it has something to do with `promisify`? I'm suspecting it does, since I have stubbed lots of other functions that return promises but that was the first one to raise such error.

How can I correctly stub `jwt.verify` in this case?

EDIT:

`jwt.verify` comes from [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package and has the following signature:

```js
jwt.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, [options, callback])
```

Comment: Hm... I thought you could promisify any function that takes a callback... Am I wrong? In this case, how do I know if a function can be promisifed or not? @JaromandaX

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I edited the post with the required information. However I found [this thread](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/111) stating that the callback is useless since the whole operation is synchronous... So I removed the promisify and the await, and called `jwt.verify()` directly, not passing a callback. Then the stub worked. It seems to me that that's not the best thing to do - Express documentation says synchronous functions are bad for performance. But if `verify` is sync, what else could I do?

Comment: damn, sorry, totally misread the question

Comment: Async only make sense when you will be waiting for something.  Verifying a JWT is something that can be done quickly and all on the CPU so it doesn't make any sense to have a promise that would just add more overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { promisify } from "util";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

async function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  const [type, token] = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
  try {
    // @ts-ignore
    const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.SECRET || "");
    // @ts-ignore
    // eslint-disable-next-line require-atomic-updates
    req.userId = decoded.id;
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid token." });
  }
}

export { verifyToken };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { verifyToken } from ".";
import sinon from "sinon";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { expect } from "chai";

const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

describe("63795862", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  it("should return next and inject user id into the request", async () => {
    const req = { userId: "", headers: { authorization: "Bearer 1234577920fsdaf" } };
    const res = {};
    const next = sandbox.stub();

    const verifyStub = sandbox.stub(jwt, "verify").callsFake((token, secretOrPublicKey, callback: any) => {
      callback(null, { id: "bj435çsfkj" });
    });

    await verifyToken(req, res, next);
    sandbox.assert.calledWithExactly(verifyStub, "1234577920fsdaf", "", sinon.match.func);
    expect(req.userId).to.equal("bj435çsfkj");
    expect(next.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });

  it("should return 401 status error", async () => {
    const req = { userId: "", headers: { authorization: "Bearer 1234577920fsdaf" } };
    const res = { status: sandbox.stub().returnsThis(), json: sandbox.stub() };
    const next = sandbox.stub();
    const mError = new Error("invalid token");
    sandbox.stub(jwt, "verify").callsFake((token, secretOrPublicKey, callback: any) => {
      callback(mError);
    });

    await verifyToken(req, res, next);

    expect(req.userId).to.equal("");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.status, 401);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(res.json, { message: "Invalid token." });
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  63795862
    ✓ should return next and inject user id into the request
    ✓ should return 401 status error


  2 passing (24ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/63795862